# RDLC Report: Child Table (Present in Row of Parent Table) not showing the Parent Table Header when grow on more than one page

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I am using RDLC reports and I have a report in which I have used a table and grouped it with a child table.

[Report]

[image]

In the pic, you can see three rows in the parent table. I have checked the properties for the parent table to show the header on each new page. Which is showing fine.
The problem is when the child table (present in the 3rd row) grows and uses the next page, the parent table doesn't show the header.
Is there anything I can do about it?

[Child Table Values]

[image]

I have tried using properties like "KeepWithGroup" "RepeatOnNewPage", but nothing happened.